# App getting crashed on `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement`

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using `UICollectionView`, On scrolling to specific part of `UICollectionView` i write an extension on `UICollectionView` that is working fine on iPhone 6 & also on simulator but in iPhone 5 app get crashed i debug it but can't able to find what the issue is.

Here is my code

```
extension UICollectionView {

func scrollToIndexpathByShowingHeader(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let sections = self.numberOfSections

    if indexPath.section <= sections {

        let attributes = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)
        let topOfHeader = CGPoint(x: 0, y: attributes!.frame.origin.y - self.contentInset.top)
        self.setContentOffset(topOfHeader, animated:false)

    }
 }

}
```

on `let attributes = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath)`
 my app getting crashed and the reason of the crash is :

`reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader at path <NSIndexPath: 0x1564e0b0> {length = 2, path = 18 - 1}'`

kindly let me know what is problem and how to solve that 
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the cell can not retrieve layoutAttributes. layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath returns nil if cell which will be created by update is not visible.

I think below solution will you.

override layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath have to use this method:

**Swift 3.0** 
for header method, Hope it will help you

```
override func layoutAttributesForItemscrollToSection(at_ indexPathsection: IndexPathInt) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
   //set Contentoffset to particular section
}
```

Comment: i can't understand this. kindly elaborate me more. @Jaydeep

Comment: previous answer is correct `layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)` kindly re-edit to that so i can aacept

Comment: @asimabbasi, Strange :)

Comment: i can't understand firstly what to do